# ToolTip to show validation errors works for TextBlock bound to POCO but not Property within POCO. Why?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

In my WPF MVVM project I use INotifyDataErrorinfo to handle validation within a DataGrid. I can successfully style error cells in my "Operator" column thus:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Operator" Width="140">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Operator}">
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OperatorId, Converter={StaticResource IsOperatorIdNullConverter}}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget}">
                                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)}" DisplayMemberPath="ErrorContent"/>
                                                </ToolTip>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Salmon"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <controls:AutoCompleteBox Text="{Binding Operator, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data.OperatorNames, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"
                                              IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
                                              FilterMode="Contains"
                                              MinimumPrefixLength="3"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

In my "OperatorType" column however this same technique doesn't work. Errors are being detected and the system default error styling is shown but my custom styling isn't. The code is:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Operator type" Width="140">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding OperatorType.OperatorTypeName}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget}">
                                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)}" DisplayMemberPath="ErrorContent"/>
                                        </ToolTip>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Salmon"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <controls:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data.OperatorTypeNames, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"
                                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AutoCompleteBoxItemOperatorTypeTemplate}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding OperatorType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                          ValueMemberPath="OperatorTypeName"
                                          IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
                                          FilterMode="Contains"
                                          MinimumPrefixLength="3"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The only differences as far as I can see are that:

1. The Text in "Operator" is using bound to a POCO (Operator) while for "OperatorType" it is bound to a POCO property (OperatorType.OperatorTypeName)
2. The AutoCompleteBox declarations are slightly different

I've tried numerous settings for the ToolTip DataContext but nothing seems to work.

**Question**

What do I need to change to get the "OperatorType" customised error styling to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was a bit of a journey, but the solution was to set a DataContext on the TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding OperatorType}" Text="{Binding OperatorTypeName}">
```

This causes the Trigger to be pointed at the OperatorType POCO whereas the Text in the box is taken from OperatorType.OperatorTypeName.